# Which interface does AddRange() belong to in List<T>?

Tags: c#, list, addrange

`List<T>` implements the following interfaces:

```
IList<T>
ICollection<T>
IList
ICollection
IReadOnlyList<T>
IReadOnlyCollection<T>
IEnumerable<T>
IEnumerable
```

None of them has `AddRange()`.

Which interface does `AddRange()` belong to in `List<T>`?

Comment: [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netcore-3.1) doesn't implement any interface method and belongs to `List<T>` itself